# How to create clustered index on Foriegn Key-Sql Server

Tags: sql, .net, database, sql-server-2008

How to create clustered index on a foreign key field in SQL Server

```
   ALTER TABLE [PERSON_MAIL] ADD 
   CONSTRAINT [PERSON_MAIL_Person_Id] 
    FOREIGN KEY CLUSTERED ([Person_Id])
    REFERENCES PERSON_KEY(Person_Id)
```

When i executing above query,getting error like "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CLUSTERED'"
Can anyone please help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a primary key you have the option to make the index created by sql server to be either clustered or non-clustered.

When creating a foreign key sql server does not create an index so there is no option for the kind of index.

You need to create the foreign key and index separately.

```
alter table foo
add constraint fk_bar(bar_id) foreign key
references bar(id)
go

create clustered index ix_foo__bar_id
on foo(bar_id)
go
```

Comment: i will test it and let u know the output

Answer (score 0):

here is solution, if you dont have primary key PERSON_KEY on:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX Idx_Person
    ON PERSON_KEY (Person_Id); 


BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tmp_PERSON_KEY
    (
    Person_Id int NOT NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tmp_PERSON_KEY SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.PERSON_KEY)
     EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.Tmp_PERSON_KEY (Person_Id)
        SELECT Person_Id FROM dbo.PERSON_KEY WITH (HOLDLOCK TABLOCKX)')
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.PERSON_KEY
GO
EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.Tmp_PERSON_KEY', N'PERSON_KEY', 'OBJECT' 
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.PERSON_KEY ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_PERSON_KEY PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
    (
    Person_Id
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX Idx_Person ON dbo.PERSON_KEY
    (
    Person_Id
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
COMMIT


  ALTER TABLE [PERSON_MAIL] ADD 
   CONSTRAINT [PERSON_MAIL_Person_Id] 
    FOREIGN KEY ([Person_Id])
    REFERENCES PERSON_KEY(Person_Id)
```